# React-native-fs peer dependency with RN?

Tags: react-native, npm, dependencies

```
npm WARN react-native-fs@2.16.6 requires a peer of react-native@^0.59.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-fs@2.16.6 requires a peer of react-native-windows@^0.57.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

When I run npm install these two warning appear. I know that I can solve the second by running npm install react-native-windows but I am not sure how to fix the first one.

I currently have react-native 0.63.3 running. If I try to downgrade to 0.59.5 I get a host of other issues.

Here on the react-native-fs npmjs instructions it lists that this version of reat-native-fs should be used for RN > 0.61 which only adds to my confusion as to why this isn't working.[image: react-native-fs npmjs instructions]

I can provide any other files that may be of importance. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did "npm install --save react-native-fs --legacy-peer-deps" and "react-native link react-native-fs"

And the module works fine for me.